# Typing props for Stripe injected component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, stripe-payments

I am having trouble with the typing for `this.props.stripe`. I am unsure of what type I need to put there.

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react-stripe-elements/index.d.ts#L44

`@types/react-stripe-elements` is installed.

```
        <StripeProvider apiKey="xxx">
            <div className="example">
                <h1>React Stripe Elements Example</h1>
                <Elements>
                    <CheckoutForm />
                </Elements>
            </div>
        </StripeProvider>
```

```
import React from 'react';
import {CardElement, injectStripe } from 'react-stripe-elements';

type CheckoutFormProps = {
  stripe: StripeProps
}

class CheckoutForm extends React.Component<CheckoutFormProps, {}> {
  submit = async (ev: React.SyntheticEvent) => {
    // User clicked submit
    let {token} = await this.props.stripe.createToken({name: "Name"});
    console.log(token);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="checkout">
        <p>Would you like to complete the purchase?</p>
        <CardElement />
        <button onClick={this.submit}>Purchase</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default injectStripe(CheckoutForm);
```

Error: `Cannot find name 'StripeProps.`

I have also tried `InjectedStripeProps`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Import namespace `ReactStripeElements` from `react-stripe-elements`:

```
import { ReactStripeElements } from 'react-stripe-elements'
```

Then you can reference the interface:

```
ReactStripeElements.StripeProps
```